# Run javascript and html in Virtual Browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, webserver, virtual

We have a web app running in html/javascript on a browser, pulling up data from database through Razor/MVC. It works great for adhoc reports. However we need to be able to schedule reports to run at certain intervals. Is there a way to run javascript and html in a sort of virtual browser on the server-side to scrape off the DOM elements, xml and image data from the canvas, after the charts and grids are drawn so that it can be inserted into a pdf? The reasoning behind this is to have the graph and grid in the pdf look the same as on the screen in the browser, and make it easier in the future to maintain, since changes would only have to be done in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Found products from a company called winnovative-software which seem to do the trick. Product require an URL, but it basically simulates what is seen on a browser, even runs javascript. Big plus is that viewer size can be specified, so if a grid takes up more space than can fit on a normal screen this product allows you to expand the height and width to fit it all. Only downside I have found is that compression of PDF's seem to make charts unreadable, lines, datapoints, scales etc. are disappearing, but that is a standard problem resizing a graph.